# How do I build logic into my computed field?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my database I have a computed column that concatenates two fields to create an onscreen display name. The formula for the computed column is `(([LastName]+', ')+[FirstName])`.

This formula works fine except for situations where there is a real last name but the first name is "-", a hyphen. From a data perspective, this is acceptable in some situations. In this cases, the name displays as "`Smith, -` ". In situations like this, where there is no real first name, we don't want the comma and hyphen displayed. It should display as "`Smith` ".

In my computed field, how do I build in some logic to test for a hyphen in the first name and, if it exists, build the display name accordingly?

Comment: I am getting mixed messages. If it's a hyphen do you want to show it or not? Does "no real first name" mean a hyphen, NULL, empty string, or something else?

Comment: Could you show some sample data (demonstrating all potential cases) and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AS (LastName + COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(Firstname, '-'), ''))
```